# Selenium chromedriver losing window handles. org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the following,

Chromedriver 2.41

selenium-server-standalone-3.10.0.jar

jdk 1.8.0_141

I use selenium to open multiple tabs in chrome, traverse each tab one by one and then execute some script. However I often get errors while switching window handles. Using `System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandles())` just before switching windows, I have found that the number of window handles keeps on decreasing with time and it gives `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window`.

Another odd thing is, the code will run fine once. Then it will give the error for subsequent tests, but if we leave it as is for ten mins later it will run fine again.

The code implementation is as follows,

```
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('" + *siteURL* + "')");
            for(String temp : driver.getWindowHandles()){
                if(!tabs.contains(temp)){
                    driver.switchTo().window(temp);
                    tabs.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }

        tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));

        /*** Reload tabs to reacquire the pages- Selenium loses them if it is idle for long time
         * **/
            for (int j = 0; j < tabs.size(); j++) {
                driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(j));
                driver.get(*siteURL*);

            }

        tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        for (int j = 0; j < tabs.size(); j++) {
          driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(j));
         /*Perform step 1*/
        }
```

error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window


(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:11:12.151Z'
System info: host: 'APACSGAWSBU0130', ip: '10.58.196.139', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031..., userDataDir: C:\Users\HY84957\Downloads\...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54006}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.87, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 0f98cc640eea21f2c48120f3bb901846
```

Comment: You shouldn't be running any script for that long and you should destroy/quit the driver after each test.

Comment: @JeffC Can you clarify what you mean by not to run a script for that long? I doubt length of the script is an issue unless chromedriver can't handle multiple tabs for more than a minute. Also, I am using driver.quit() always.

Comment: You said `if we leave it as is for ten mins later` so I took that to mean that you had browsers up for more than 10 minutes. We have a lot of tests, most of which run 2-3 minutes and some that run up to 10 minutes and we've never had an issue with the driver losing track of tabs. I'm not sure what you are doing that might cause that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced same issue. It take some time to `getWindowHandles()`, with `Thread.sleep(500);` it's working fine.

```
public void goto2() throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<String> winHandles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandles.get(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am still getting the erro, but it is much rarer nowso probably related to some other timing issues.

Comment: I have my program running for hours and hours. i am NOT using selenium for testing. I have noticed, that no matter what logic you build for double-triple-quadruple waiting for window handles - selenium will always start throwing `NoSuchWindowException` after 1.5-2 days of execution. I tried using delays, try/catch mechanics, retrying mechanics.. it just stops working after time. The solution that I found is to restart the service at midnight.. Sadly there are no other options than selenium for my needs and nobody from selenium is investigating this issue. Could be due to some memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public void windowHandle()
{
Set<String> allWindowHandles ==driver.getwindowHandles();
 Iterator<String> iterator = allWindowHandles.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String ChildWindow = iterator.next();
                if (!mainWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow)) {
  driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);
 WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.id("sampleHeading"))    System.out.println("Heading of child window is " + text.getText());
            }
        }
```